# Cassandra with Spark, select a few columns with case class

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, case-class

I'm trying to get a few columns from a Cassandra table from Spark and put them in a case class. If I want all the columns that I have in my case class works. But, I only want to bring a few of them and don't have a specific case class for each case.

I tried to overload constructor in the case class and define a normal class but I didn't get to work.

```
//It doesn't work, it's normal because there aren't an specific contructor.
case class Father(idPadre: Int, name: String, lastName: String, children: Map[Int,Son], hobbies: Map[Int,Hobbie],  lastUpdate: Date)
//It works, because it has the right contructor. I tried to do an companion object and def others contructors but it didn't work
case class FatherEspecifica(idFather: Int, name: String, children: Map[Int,Son])
//Problems in compilation, I don't know why. 
class FatherClaseNormal(idFather: Int, name: String, lastName: String, children: Map[Int,Son], hobbies: Map[Int,Hobbie],  lastUpdate: Date){
  /**
    * A secondary constructor.
    */
  def this(nombre: String) {
    this(0, nombre, "", Map(), Map(), new Date());
    println("\nNo last name or age given.")
  }
}

//I'm trying to get some a few columns and don't have to have all the case classes and I would like to map directly to case class and don't use CassandraRows.
joinRdd = rddAvro.joinWithCassandraTable[FatherXXX]("poc_udt", "father",SomeColumns("id_father", "name", "children"))

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS poc_udt.father(
    id_father int PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    last_name text,
    children map<int,frozen<son>>,
    hobbies map<int,frozen<hobbie>>,
    last_update timestamp
)
```

When I use a normal class the error is:

```
Error:(57, 67) No RowReaderFactory can be found for this type
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
    val joinRdd = rddAvro.joinWithCassandraTable[FatherClaseNormal]("poc_udt", "padre",SomeColumns("nombre"))
```